# loopback 3 manage embedsMany over REST api

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I have one loopback model `pack`

```
{
  "name": "pack",
  "plural": "packs",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description2": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "products": {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "packProduct",
      "property": "products",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {},
  "strict": true
}
```

Now the `packProduct` model

```
{
  "name": "packProduct",
  "plural": "packProducts",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "productId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {},
  "strict": true
}
```

When I am sending a POST request to create a pack with only a name it works but if I am sending

{
    name: "test",
    products: []
}

I have `The pack instance is not valid. Details: products is not defined in the model (value: undefined).`

Comment: Huh, well that's kind of weird! I replicated your setup and tried inserting it like so: `{ "name": "test", "products": [{
    "name": "t-shirt",
    "quantity": "3"
  }, {
    "name": "laptop",
    "quantity": "1"
  }]
}` It worked fine. So, try to check hooks or anything that might be interfering with the normal flow.

Comment: Thanks @HarryAdel I am using loopback 3.22 connected with mongodb, it it the same for you ?

Comment: Yup, did that too. Here's my package.json:  https://gist.github.com/Harry97/caf9c034412dd93a46ffc2d729dd5a34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this part of the configuration https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html#transient-versus-persistent-for-the-embedded-model

Needs to add in `model-config.json`

```
"packProduct": {
    "dataSource": "transient",
    "public": false
}
```

And in `datasources.json`

```
"transient": {
    "name": "transient",
    "connector": "transient"
}
```